# If column header = specific value condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, if-statement

I am trying to create a condition where if the column headers in my dataframe are equal to
Unnamed: 0  VALUE   VALUE.1 VALUE.2 then i want to do drop the first two rows and rename the headers

```
Unnamed: 0       VALUE     VALUE.1        VALUE.2
Name            Hobbies     Dislikes    Favorite Color
Ben             NaN         NaN              NaN
Alex            NaN         Running          Red
Mike            NaN         Cartoons         Blue
Mark            NaN         Pizza            Yellow
```

I know i can do

```
     df = df.drop([0,1])
```

but i need it to be conditional

I tried doing

```
if df.columns = {"Unnamed: 0", "VALUE", "VALUE.1", "VALUE.2"}:
     df = df.drop([0,1])
     df = df.rename(columns={"Unnamed: 0": "Name", "VALUE": "Hobbies", "VALUE.1": "Dislikes", "VALUE.2": "Favorite Color"})
```

but i'm running into a syntax error where i am trying to create a condition with my column names. Any clue how to fix this?

Comment: If you can, try to **prevent** this problem rather than fixing it. This will avoid assigning the wrong dtypes in case you don't have only strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
cols = pd.Index(['Unnamed:0', 'VALUE', 'VALUE.1', 'VALUE.2'])
if df.columns.equals(cols):
    df = df.set_axis(df.iloc[0], axis=1).iloc[1:]
print(df)
>>>
    Name    Hobbies Dislikes    Favorite    Color
1   Ben     NaN     NaN         NaN         None
2   Alex    NaN     Running     Red         None
3   Mike    NaN     Cartoons    Blue        None
4   Mark    NaN     Pizza       Yellow      None
```

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you. One small edit is that the first column name is 'Unnamed: 0'

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you only need to drop row 0 cause columns is not a row.

Then the == should be used in the if statement, and it's a list comparison, so add .all()

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Unnamed: 0", "VALUE", "VALUE.1", "VALUE.2"])
df.loc[0] = ['Name', 'Hobbies', 'Dislikes', 'Favorite Color']
df.loc[1] = ['Ben', None, None, None]

print(df)

if (df.columns == ["Unnamed: 0", "VALUE", "VALUE.1", "VALUE.2"]).all():
    df = df.drop([0])
    df.columns = ['Name', 'Hobbies', 'Dislikes', 'Favorite Color']
print()
print(df)
```

output:

```
  Unnamed: 0    VALUE   VALUE.1         VALUE.2
0       Name  Hobbies  Dislikes  Favorite Color
1        Ben     None      None            None

  Name Hobbies Dislikes Favorite Color
1  Ben    None     None           None
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a ':' at the end of the first line.
and the indentation

apart from that the code shouldn't give any syntax error

Comment: Hey Sabir, sorry for the confusion. I updated my code. I think that the ':' is needed and same with the condition. I ONLY want to drop rows and rename column headers if the column headers are a specific value